# In project build results, Python Pyramid referencing a view source file that no longer exists

Tags: python, pyramid

In a Python Pyramid project, I tried to rename a project view file temporarily while testing a new version of this file. Originally, the project started with the following view file:

```
/myproject/myproject/views/default.py
```

I then renamed this file to some other temporary name:

```
/myproject/myproject/views/stable_default.py
```

and created a new `default.py` in the same directory for testing purpose. The idea was that I could return to my starting point by removing the new `default.py` and again renaming `stable_default.py` back to `default.py`.

However, after building the project (using `myproject/env/bin/pip install e .`), the original/renamed view file `stable_default.py` became recognized as being part of the project (and caused various problems because there are repeating blocks of code in the 2 view files...bad choice on my part to try using this approach). Next, if I remove the file `stable_default.py`, such that it no longer exists in the source directory (or anywhere else), and try to build the project again, `stable_default.py` is still being recognized as part of the project (and causing various problems since the source file does not exist...causing the project to fail).

In searching through the project files, I found 2 file names associated with the build results that reference the non-existent view source file. In this case, I am using Python version 3.9x, which also influences the file/path names shown below:

```
/myproject/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/myproject/views/stable_default.py
```

and

```
/myproject/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/myproject/views/__pycache__/stable_default.cpython-39.pyc
```

If I simply delete the above 2 files, then all of the problems go away and the project runs properly.

I have not been able to determine what aspect of the source files or build system is holding onto the file name `stable_default.py` even after this file has been removed from the view source directory.

My workaround is to remove those 2 generated files referencing the `stable_default.py` source after each build of the project, but I would really like to fix this project such that these 2 files do get generated at all.

I suppose a more general question is...how can the developer of a Pyramid project have complete control over which view files are included or not included in the build?

Comment: `pip install e .` is not a thing. I think you mean `pip install -e .`. Aside from that, it does not build. It makes your project's source files editable and not copied. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/#editable-installs